# Submit Event Listener for a form

Tags: javascript, dom-events, form-submit

I've written an event listener for a form  submit that is causing me a few issues. When pressing 'enter' inside the text field everything works fine. However, I have an span (with background-image) that submits the form as well via a click event. This is not working properly and I can't figure out why.

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="search" />
  <span id="search-button"></span>
</form>
```

Here's the JS for the event listener:

```
function evtSubmit(e) {
  // code
  e.preventDefault();
};

var myform = document.myForm;
if (myform.addEventListener) {
  myform.addEventListener('submit', evtSubmit, false);
}
```

And here's the JS for the 'span' and its click event:

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
if (searchButton) {
 searchButton.onclick = function() {
  document.myForm.submit();
 };
}
```

NOTE: The JS for the span's click event is in a separate JS file and inaccessible at the moment, so changing that script is less of an option. If the only way to fix this issue is to update that file, I can... but due to processes beyond my control, it's much more difficult.

Comment: This is actually a good question that would probably get more views if it was titled "Overriding the built-in Javascript submit method on a Form"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When calling `form.submit()`, the `onsubmit` event won't be triggered. As an alternative, you can set the action attribute to `javascript:evtSubmit(event)`:

```
function evtSubmit(e) {
  // code
  e.preventDefault();
};

var myform = document.myForm;
myform.setAttribute('action', 'javascript:evtSubmit();');
```

Comment: gotcha. would rewriting the 'submit' event on the prototype object solve the issue?

Comment: Man, you save my day! :)

Comment: @raphael75 Try `javascript:evtSubmit(event)` as suggested above the code