# Submit event listener for an AJAX form

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, addeventlistener

I am unable to get an event listener to fire on forms that use AJAX. I don't have control over the inline structure of these forms.

Ultimately, I want to disable the form submit, but for development, a simple message to the console would be great. Disabling the form submit is explained well in this question : [Submit Event Listener for a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841298/submit-event-listener-for-a-form), and on my non-AJAX forms, works perfectly.

Since I can't control the inline structure of the forms, I loop through all forms and assign an event listener to each.

```
var vForms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
for(i=0; i<vForms.length; i++){

    vForms[i].addEventListener('submit', event => {
       console.log('FORM SUBMITTED : ' + event);
    });

}
```

I've also tried .onSubmit

```
vForms[i].onsubmit = function(e){
    console.log('FORM SUBMITTED : ' + e);
};
```

Using either approach, no errors show during the loop that indicates the .addEventListener or .onSubmit didn't work.

I've tried putting the loop after a long delay, just to see if they were loading after the code first ran, but a delay far longer than the load time didn't help.

I also tried disabling the AJAX loading, to ensure that is really the problem, and it worked after doing so and didn't after re-enabling it.

Thank you in advance for any help you may provide.

Comment: Add a click listener on the submit button, not the form. Then you can use preventDefault() to stop the action.

Comment: This workaround along with an [Enter] press listener is an approach I will implement until a better solution is devised.

Is there anything about async forms that may be causing this problem?